# Images enlarge on hover but vertical images not returning to normal on mouseout

Tags: jquery

Horizontal images enlarge and return to normal but vertical images enlarge and then return horizontal not vertical. I have [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/RwJhn/). I'm not sure but believe the issue is in jQuery. I'm very new to jQuery but this seems to be the only way to achieve what I need since each image is also a form submit button. This can be seen at www.starcuts10.com/poems

CSS:

```
#container {
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
    position: relative;
}

.img {
    position: relative;
    z-index: 0;
}

.end {
    margin-right: 0;
}

.clear {
    clear: both;
}

.img a img {
    position: relative;
    border: 0 solid #fff;
 }

.form_align {
    display: inline;
    float: left:
}
```

jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var cont_left = $("#container").position().right;

    if ($('span').hasClass('horz')) {
        $("input").hover(function() {
            // hover in
            $(this).parent().parent().css("z-index", 1);
            $(this).animate({
                height: "405",
                width: "638",
                right: "+=50",
                bottom: "+=150"
            }, "fast");
        }, 
        function() {
            // hover out
            $(this).parent().parent().css("z-index", 0);
            $(this).animate({
                height: "250",
                width: "425",
                right: "-=50",
                bottom: "-=150"
            }, "fast");
        });


        $(".img").each(function(index) {
            var right = (index * 160) + cont_left;
            $(this).css("right", right + "px");
        });
    } 
    else {
        $("input").hover(function() {
            // hover in
            $(this).parent().parent().css("z-index", 1);
            $(this).animate({
                height: "638",
                width: "405",
                right: "+=50",
                bottom: "+=150"
            }, "fast");
        }, 
        function() {
            // hover out
            $(this).parent().parent().css("z-index", 0);
            $(this).animate({
                height: "425",
                width: "250",
                right: "-=50",
                bottom: "-=150"
            }, "fast");
        });

        $(".img").each(function(index) {
            var right = (index * 160) + cont_left;
            $(this).css("right", right + "px");
        });
    }
});
```

HTML:

```
<div id="container">
    <table>
        <tr>
            <span class="horz">
                <span class="vert">    
                    <td>
                        <form class="form_align" method ="post" action="#">
                            <a href=""><input type="image" src="http://starcuts10.com/images/blue_box.png" class="img"></a>
                            <input type="hidden" name="img" value="http://starcuts10.com/images/blue_box.png"> 
                            <input type="hidden" name="poem" value="">
                        </form>
                    </td>
                </span>
                <span class="vert">    
                <td>
                    <form class="form_align" method ="post" action="#">
                        <a href=""><input type="image" src="http://starcuts10.com/images/red_box.png" class="img"></a>
                        <input type="hidden" name="img" value="http://starcuts10.com/images/red_box.png"> 
                        <input type="hidden" name="poem" value="">
                    </form>
                </td>
            </span>  
        </tr>
    </table><br><br><br>
</div>
```

Comment: Seems like your html is wrong. First, rewrite your html code and use indentation to make it more readable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is something wrong with you jquery logic.

You don't need `if ("span.horz") { .. } else { .. }`

what you need to do is have the hover effect on both: `$(".horz input")` and `$(".vert input")`.

Also, the html is wrong. spans should be inside the TDs

This is a working fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/RwJhn/1/

Comment: You are a life saver! I love this site and the help everyone provides !  Thank you!!!!!

Comment: How do I give you a medal or badge or someting for your help?

Comment: you can't give badges, it would be nice though. You can vote up and mark this comment as answered